# How to integrate Keycloak into simple Spring Boot back-end with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm currently trying to implement security for a simple Spring Boot Back-End application. For that I intended to use Keycloak in combination with Spring Security. After trying a dozens of tutorial set-ups (just a basic filter / SecurityConfig), I'm left clueless as to why the `SecurityFilterChain` won't work.

As a reference - the following are my dependencies:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.0
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.1.0
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.1.0
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.1.0
- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.0

all with Spring Boot 3.1.0! Due to the fact that the online material was from the last two years, I also tried different versions through (e.g. `<spring-security.version>6.1.1</spring-security.version>`, etc.)

As to my `application.properties` I added the most basic set-up:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=[client-id]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/dev
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

That's that! Now onto the different approaches I've went through *unsuccessfully*:

[**1. Tutorial from Baeldung**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak)

On there it specified the SecurityConfig to be used with a `@Bean` returning a `SecurityFilterChain`:

```
 @Bean
 public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/customers*")
             .hasRole("USER")
             .anyRequest()
             .permitAll();
     http.oauth2Login()
             .and()
             .logout()
             .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
             .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
     http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
     return http.build();
 }
```

... Apparently, `'authorizeRequests()'` is deprecated. Same applies for `'oauth2Login()'` (even marked for removal)!

[**2. GitHub Issue #10187 discussion**](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187#discussioncomment-2203263)

In the before-mentioned issue, a in-depth discussion broke out with lots of members sharing their code snippet. It's a very recent topic (2022) and thus I thought it would still apply to current standards.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests() //
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() //
                .and().oauth2Client() //
                .and().oauth2Login().tokenEndpoint().and().userInfoEndpoint().userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapper()) //
                .and().and()
                .logout().addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
        ;
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
    [...]
```

I played with something along those lines. Again... Besides the known culprits marked as `deprecated` (`oauth2Client()`, `oauth2Login()`, etc.) the big issue was [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.0-M2/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) is **ALSO** deprecated. When opening [issue #12514](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/12514) I was then informed that I should proceed with a `SecurityFilterChain` similar to the first approach.

Either way, I've burnt through approximately 10+ tutorials now and am not able to find one working project which is - considering the size of KeyCloak - very odd. The only good information I found was that the old [KeyCloak adapters were deprecated](https://www.keycloak.org/2023/03/adapter-deprecation-update.html) as of last year... though I haven't used them as you can see above.

**Is anyone able to help me out?** I want to set-up a **SIMPLE** `SecurityConfig` to build by base upon. Just fetching the bearer token (btw KeyCloak related set-up works) from the request, then validating the JWT and comparing the user roles / permissions to the needed role on an endpoint *(preferably not a global setting, but a local one per endpoint basis)*.

Comment: On a slight off-topic note (as it couldn't be seen in the dependencies), I'm using Maven.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), **starting with the OAuth2 essential section of the introduction readme**. All samples and tutorials work with Keycloak (with and without "my" starters).

Comment: Thanks @ch4mp! I've went through your material and it seems like an in-depth explanation of the topic. Though my question remains: Aren't there any small configurations (such as all the "old" tutorials imply) to basic test JWT tokens issued by KeyCloak? I just want to test securing some endpoints and go on from there...

Comment: It is certainly not "in depth". If you don't master these essentials, you'll have no idea of what you are actually configuring (and why your app doesn't behave as you expect). If you mean something simpler than [that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default), no.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you accept identities issued by 3 different OIDC authorization-servers? Like in most set-ups you use one server (e.g. setting up KeyCloak for my project)? @ch4mp

Comment: I have projects with separate OpenID Providers for "corporate users" and "clients". I have others where most APIs (resource server) accept identities from a "relaxed" (public) OP, but some critical APIs (healthcare) require identities from an OP with reinforced security (multi-factor authentication and firewall making the OP accessible from the local network only). Last, I have cases where a client uses a main OP to communicate with "my" resource servers and maintain a Google identity to issue direct calls to Google APIs.

Comment: In the specific case of these tutorials, it has a double benefit: demoes that multi-tenancy is rather easy to achieve and illustrates working configuration for 3 of the most frequently used OPs.

Comment: But in reality, it would be most likely to just implement one provider, right? I mean if KeyCloak is properly configured, it would suffice? @ch4mp

Comment: Furthermore, do you have a tutorial on how to use advanced log-in methods like "Log-in with Google", "Apple Log-In" and so forth? Preferably with KeyCloak? Like similar to your current tutorials.

Comment: No, and no. When different groups of resource servers trust different authorization servers, OAuth2 clients have to maintain access tokens for each of this groups. For instance, an app calling both a corporate API trusting corporate Keycloak and Google APIs trusting its own authorization server (you can't call Google API with a token issued by your Keycloak, even if it was using "Log-in with Google"). You'll find how to configure "Log-in with Google" in Keycloak in docs and on many tutorials, but not in mine: it is not related to Spring.

Comment: But for my understanding: We’re currently developing a back-end for multiple front-ends (an app, websites, etc.) - but everything internal. In such a set-up one would need one authorization server (like Keycloak) and that would suffice? Or am I misunderstanding this..? Can you give a concrete example of where two or more OPs are useful?

Comment: Furthermore, do you want to add your answer to my question? I’d like to upvote and accept it. Your tutorial only uses a few deprecated methods (in comparison to most non-working tutorials)! @ch4mp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Spring app just acts as an resource server, see my example here:
https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-bookshop-demo/tree/master/msgbroker

In the dependencies, there's just the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`.
The `application.properties` just need the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` configured and the [SecurityConfig](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-bookshop-demo/blob/master/msgbroker/src/main/java/dasniko/keycloak/shop/broker/SecurityConfig.java) class is also small and lean.